# Sort by array index using Realm and NSPredicate

Tags: nspredicate, realm

I have an array of IDs: [INT]. Now I want to select all the objects have these ids but need to follow the order of id in the IDs array.

```
let IDs = [2, 6, 3, 4, 10, 9]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", IDs)
let objects = realm.objects(Item.self).filter(predicate)
```

But in the end, objects was ordered in a different way with IDs. Is there any way that I can sort this objects to the correct order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `sort()`:

```
let IDs = [2, 6, 3, 4, 10, 9]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", IDs)    
do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    let objects = realm.objects(Item).filter(predicate).sort({ IDs.indexOf($0.id) < IDs.indexOf($1.id) })
} catch {        
}
```

Comment: This approach will materialize Swift class instances of every single object matching the query to perform the sort operation. Use `Results.sorted(_:)` to avoid this eager materialization. This approach is good (necessary even) for applying a custom sorting algorithm not supported by Realm, however.

Comment: Thanks. This works. However, we will need to materialize all the objects before using .sort . Results.sorted is not capable of detecting the order of id in IDs array though.

Comment: The question asked for a custom sorting algorithm, so there is no way around materializing the objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Realm, `Results` conforms to the `RealmCollectionType` protocol, which has a [`sorted(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Protocols/RealmCollectionType.html#/s:FP10RealmSwift19RealmCollectionType6sortedu__Rq_S0_qd__Ss12SequenceTypezqqqd__S1_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementVS_14SortDescriptor_Fq_Fqd__GCS_7Resultsqq_S0_7Element_) member function. This function takes a sequence of [`SortDescriptor`s](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Structs/SortDescriptor.html), which are `StringLiteralConvertible`, making them pretty easy to use:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let IDs = [2, 6, 3, 4, 10, 9]
let objects = realm.objects(Item).filter("id IN %@", IDs).sorted(["id"])
```

Comment: I tried to use sorted("id") but it is not what I need. I want to order items by the order of their id in array IDs.

Comment: I see. Then joern's answer is the best way to do this for now.